# Is it culturally insensitive to give a cat a Khajiit name?

Tags: names, the-elder-scrolls

This may sound random, but I was watching a video where a guy was playing *[Elder Kings 2](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2887120253)*. In the game, he got a pet cat and he was thinking about giving it a Khajiit name because Khajiit look like cats, but he said he thought it would be culturally insensitive.

Is there any evidence in-world that would prove that Khajiit would actually take offense at having a cat named after them?

Comment: Given how ‘culturally insensitive’ some of the town guards are (well, were after mouthing off to me) I don’t think it would be unusual…

Comment: That sounds like a barb thrown at the Woke Police. But would calling it Chmee be rayciss to Kzinti? Oh ok, back to work.

Comment: Just FYI, Khajiit can look like normal cats.

Answer (score 5):

Is a Khajiiti name for a regular pet cat offensive or insensitive? I'd say it's most likely not:

What we typically consider Khajiit names (like Khamira, Razum-dar, Shuzera, Garesh-ri, etc.) are all more or less just names originating from their language, Ta'agra. Affixes such as `dar`, `ri`, `do` and others are very similar to Asian affixes, like the Japanese `kun` or `san`, although they might carry more weight or specifics about an individual.

That being said, I'd say calling your regular cat by a Khajiit name wouldn't be that different compared to calling your cat "Lee" or "Kami-sama" in the real world.

Would Khajiit take offense? From the name alone, most likely not. Maybe some might even see it as a kind of nod to their own culture or heritage in a certain way. Last but not least if the owner is a Khajiit, nobody would even question the decision.

For example, in **The Elder Scrolls Online** on the **Laughing Moons Plantation** (Khenarthi's Roost) **Cinder-Tail** (a Khajiiti name translated to modern Cyrodiilian, which we perceive as English) has several pet senche (Gobani, Marapa, Radusha, and Sayya-daro) he complains about, because they stopped killing the rats plaguing the farm.

Last but not least it's also very plausible Khajiit might abuse names the other way around:

In **Southern Elsweyr** the player may find a note about a supposedly abandoned cat named **Tender Claw**. The player is supposed to bring that cat back home to **Senchal**.

> During the quest it's exposed that the pet's "owner", Kishima, is actually the "pets" sister after revealing he's actually an Alfiq, a thief regularly abusing his body stature and people thinking he's a regular cat.

The game mentions several other similar instances in books and notes, especially surrounding Alfiq actually acting as spies, pretending to be regular cats. As such, it could even be possible the other Alliances (or even races in general) would potentially take way more offense at Khajiiti names for pets (compared to Khajiit), since it would leave that slight possibility of an unwelcomed spy or thief amongst them.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, but doubtful.

I met lots of dogs with human names - one of the more popular is shared with the current ruler of Great Britain. I doubt that he is offended because "Charlie" is a popular dog's name. My IRL dog's name is "Arnie" and so far I didn't got a threat from the Governator.

Saying that I think there would be one case when Khajiit would take offence:

You see, while the playable Khajiit look all similar (humanoids with cat-like faces), there are in fact about 17 [different breeds](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Khajiit#Furstocks), which all depend on the time of birth (so a child can be a different "furstock" than their parents). One of them, Alfiq, is indistinguishable from regular housecats:

[image]

> The Alfiq are a diminutive form of magically gifted Khajiit resembling typical housecats. Their resemblance to common housecats has led many to treat them as such, whether by downplaying their intelligence, cooing at them or attempting to cuddle them. [...] Due to the disrespect that Alfiq get as a result of their form, they rarely travel outside Elsweyr.All these factors resulted in **Alfiq resenting being labeled as housecats, which they consider patronizing and irritating**.

Calling a regular cat just like one of those deeply respected magicians would be treated at beast as in bad taste.